# Linq: Order of execution chain query

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, ienumerator

I want to understand how chain query is processed. For example, let us consider the following query

```
var sumOfRoots = numbers           //IEnum0
     .Where(x => x > 0)            //IEnum1
     .Select(x => Math.Sqrt(x))    //IEnum2
     .Select(x => Math.Exp(x))     //IEnum3
     .Sum();
```

where e.g. `numbers={-1, 4, 9 }.`

Is this what happends behind the scene:

**1. Getting all enumerators (forward pass)**

- `numbers` calls `GetEnumerator()` which returns (let us denote it with) `IEnum0` instance
- `IEnum0` calls `GetEnumerator()` which returns `IEnum1` instance
- `IEnum1` calls `GetEnumerator()` which returns `IEnum2` instance
- `IEnum2` calls `GetEnumerator()` which returns `IEnum3` instance

**2. Calling MoveNext (backward pass)**

- `.Sum()` calls `MoveNext()` on `IEnum3`
- `IEnum3` calls `MoveNext()` on `IEnum2`
- `IEnum2` calls `MoveNext()` on `IEnum1`
- `IEnum1` calls `MoveNext()` on `IEnum0`

**3. Returning from MoveNext (forward-backward pass)**

- `IEnum0` moves to element `-1` and return `true`.
- `IEnum1` check if `-1` satisfy condition (which is not true) so `IEnum1` calls `MoveNext()` on `IEnum0`.
- `IEnum0` moves to element `4` and return `true`.
- `IEnum1` check if `4` satisfy condition (which is true) and returns `true`
- `IEnum2` does nothing, just return output of `IEnum1` which is `true`
- `IEnum2` does nothing, just return output of `IEnum2` which is `true`

**4. Calling Current (backward pass)**

- `.Sum()` calls `Current` on `IEnum3`.
- `IEnum3` calls `Current` on `IEnum2`
- `IEnum2` calls `Current` on `IEnum1`
- `IEnum1` calls `Current` on `IEnum0`

**5. Returning Current (forward pass)**

- `IEnum0` returns `4`
- `IEnum1` returns `4`
- `IEnum2` returns `sqrt(4)=2`
- `IEnum3` returns `exp(2)`

**6. Repeat steps 2.-5. until step 3. returns false**

Please correct me if a chain query is processed in a different way.

Comment: The processes are completed within every block of chain. Where(x => x > 0) filters numbers and leaves out {4,9} for next block and it goes on like that.

Comment: You could use the 'debug framework code' feature of Visual Studio and see it live while debugging. Alternatively, go to [reference sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3), copy the methods to your solution and debug it.

Comment: Mostly correct, but I never think about chain query like that because LINQ is invented to preventing us thinking data pipeline as loop/iterator.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I don't understand your comment, how processing within every block will work? This seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use delegates to understand the order of execution. Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new []{ -1, 4, 9 };

    double sumOfRoots = numbers.Where(IsGreaterThanZero)   
                               .Select(ToSquareRoot)      
                               .Select(ToExp)              
                               .Sum(x => ToNumber(x));

    Console.WriteLine($"sumOfRoots = {sumOfRoots}");

    Console.Read();
}

private static double ToNumber(double number)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"SumNumber({number})");

    return number;
}

private static double ToSquareRoot(int number)
{
    double value =  Math.Sqrt(number);

    Console.WriteLine($"Math.Sqrt({number}): {value}");

    return value;
}

private static double ToExp(double number)
{
    double value =  Math.Exp(number);

    Console.WriteLine($"Math.Exp({number}): {value}");

    return value;
}

private static bool IsGreaterThanZero(int number)
{
    bool isGreater = number > 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"{number} > 0: {isGreater}");

    return isGreater;
}
```

Output:

> -1 > 0: False
>
> 4 > 0: True
>
> Math.Sqrt(4): 2
>
> Math.Exp(2): 7.38905609893065
>
> SumNumber(7.38905609893065)
>
> 9 > 0: True
>
> Math.Sqrt(9): 3
>
> Math.Exp(3): 20.0855369231877
>
> SumNumber(20.0855369231877)
>
> sumOfRoots = 27.4745930221183

Comment: Damn, I never thought LINQ queries chain like this, good idea to use the delegates.